# How to monitor GCM errors on Google Developer Console

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine

https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=1

Shows that there are 0 requests and 60 errors - this increases every time I attempt to make a request, how do I view errors?

Answer (score -1):

Choose the project you want to preview then `Monitoring` > `Logs` in the left panel.

Comment: it says "Nothing has been logged yet". Even though there are now 170 errors